"It's a span of a few hundred miles to cross the state." — By what rule was this sentence made up?
britannica.com:
(1) It's a span of a few hundred miles to cross the state.
As I understand, (1) means:
(2) We need to cover a span of a few hundred miles in order to cross the state.
But I can't understand by what rule (1) was made up. It doesn't look like an ordinary extraposition to me because if it represents one then the initial sentence is:
(3) To cross the state is a span of a few hundred miles.
The presence of the verb "is" (and therefore the whole sentence) doesn't make sense to me here. So I can't consider (1) as an example of extraposition.

It's an abstract statement of how far anyone would need to travel, not just "we."

@Mary If we replace "we" with "one", will (2) sound good: "One needs to cover a span of a few hundred miles in order to cross the state." ? Thanks.

Yes, (1) is an extraposition.
In (3),

[To cross the state] is [a span of a few hundred miles].

the noun phrase after the copula is the subject complement, and the sentence is fine.

Does (1) remain correct if we remove "a span of": "It's a few hundred miles to cross the state." ? Thanks.

Yes, (1) remains correct in that situation.
